# Does using Battle Stones count as "leveling pets yourself"?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

For the Tournament of Celestials on Pandaria, you need to have levelled 15 pets to level 25 yourself. I assume that means you level them all the way from 1-25 yourself, instead of just like...buying 15 level 25 pets.

But you can get Battle Stones through various means, that add levels to your pets. Do pets levelled this way still count as "levelling them yourself", or do you have to grind levels the "natural" way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using battle stones to level your pets counts towards the [Pro Pet Group](https://www.wowhead.com/achievement=6578/pro-pet-group) achievement which you need to unlock the Celestial Tournament.

I have leveled several pets with battle stones and have confirmed they counted towards the achievement.